# Laravel Validators - Serialization of UploadedFile is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently trying to setup a Laravel project on IIS and so far everything works as it should. The only problem is that when I try to validate my form that is being submitted it crashes with the error `Serialization of 'Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed'`

This happens on the following section of code:

```
    $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required',
        'short_title' => 'required|between:1,15',
        //'alias' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'province' => 'required',
        'start_datetime' => 'required|date',
        'url' => 'required',
        'max_entries' => 'required|numeric',
        'fee_sub' => 'numeric',
        'fee_class_batch' => 'numeric',
        'fee_class_batch_unpaid' => 'numeric',
        'fee_class_batch_t' => 'numeric',
        'fee_class_batch_t_unpaid' => 'numeric',
        'fee_team_remove' => 'numeric'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

If I comment out the last line the form submit works without error. So it has something to do with that `Input::all(), $rules`.

Does someone know why this is happening?